# Premiere Pro: How to add multiple masks for Lumetri Color effect?

Tags: effects, color-correction, premiere-pro

I'm expected to do color correction to multiple separate parts of the same clip at the same time, which is why I have assumed using multiple masks for Lumetri Color effect and changing the effect for each mask would affect the part that is masked. However, it seems having multiple masks doesn't matter: It adds the same effect color change to each mask. How is it that I can use Lumetri Color to make a color correction on the same part of the clip but with different colors on each mask? After searching on YouTube, the results returned how to use one mask.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer!

It works by duplicating the clip and placing it on a track right above (or below), masking each so it only shows the part that is color-corrected as well with no need to mask with Lumetri Color, and the final step is to add the clip that includes the background. That final clip can also be using Lumetri Color but without masking required as long as this is the bottom track.

In order for them to look more natural, I used feathering to make the masks less sharp.